# Почему не одинаково отрабатывает многопоточность java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Блинов и Романчик в книге **Java методы программирования**, по вопросу многопоточности написали (стр.295):

```java
public class YieldRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread() { // анонимный класс
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("старт потока 1");
        Thread.yield();
        System.out.println("завершение 1");
      }
    }.start(); // запуск потока
    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("старт потока 2");
        System.out.println("завершение 2");
      }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

Авторы пишут далее, цитирую:

> В результате может быть выведено:

```
старт потока 1 
старт потока 2
завершение 2
завершение 1
```

Я запустил это сначала у себя в `Intellij IDEA`, потом на одном внешнем компиляторе, получил:

```
старт потока 1
завершение 1
старт потока 2
завершение 2
```

Потом я запустил на другом внешнем компиляторе и получил как у авторов результат. Похоже я наблюдал неодинаковость работы многопоточности.

**Вопрос**: как объясняется такое различие в работе сред выполнения?

Comment: Порядок выполнения потоков непредсказуем.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Здесь не о порядке выполнения потоков идет речь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представьте, что два человека идут по параллельным тропинкам. Оба должны пройти точку А и точку Б. Первый выходит на пару секунд раньше, а после точки А, он еще должен будет завязать шнурки (вызов метода `Thread.yield()`). Вопрос: в каком порядке они пройдут точки А и Б?

Напрашивается ответ, что т.к. первый вышел раньше, то он раньше пройдет точку А, но т.к. он завязывал шнурки, то второй пройдет раньше точку Б. Но это не верно, т.к. на тропинках у обоих могут лежать разные ветки, которые либо замедлят движение, либо ускорят.

Единственное, что можно сказать наверняка, что первый и второй достигнут точки А перед тем, как достигнуть точки Б

---

**Update**

Чтобы обеспечить детерминированность выполнения программы в многопоточной среде, нужно использовать [объекты синхронизации](https://habr.com/post/277669/). В данном случае подойдет [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

```
public class YieldRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CyclicBarrier signal = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    new Thread() { // анонимный класс
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("старт потока 1");
        signal.await();  // Отпускаем второй поток
        signal.await();  // Ждем завершения второго потока
        System.out.println("завершение 1");
      }
    }.start(); // запуск потока
    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        signal.await();  // Ждем разрешения продолжить
        System.out.println("старт потока 2");
        System.out.println("завершение 2");
        signal.await();  // Уведомляем, что можно продолжать
      }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Без барьера реордеринг может произойти на уровне компиляции в байткод, jit-компиляции в машинный код и выполнении процессором. Так что кто-то из них вполне может пройти Б раньше А, и это тоже непредсказуемо.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Имеется в виду возможное автоматическое распараллеливание независимых команд?

Comment: Имеется ввиду _reordering_. Компиляторы и процессоры могут переупорядочивать инструкции, если считают, что иной порядок выполнения будет оптимальнее. Простая операция инкремента может породить 12 870 путей выполнения для int и 2 704 156 для long.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev При условии, что новый порядок не меняет логики программы.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov  стало более понятно. А предсказуемость как-то можно повысить (помимо sleep)?

Comment: неверный ответ, "на тропинках у обоих могут лежать разные ветки, которые либо замедлят движение, либо ускорят."

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Да. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Что дает использование метода `Thread::yield` в потоке:

то есть, когда поток вызывает метод `yield()`, он дает хинт планировщику потоков, что он готов приостановить его выполнение. Если какой-либо поток выполняет метод `yield()`, планировщик потоков проверяет, есть ли какой-либо поток с таким же или более высоким приоритетом, как этот поток и если такого нет, то продолжает выполнение потока.

Comment: Спасибо, тоже понятно. Просто ответ предыдущего оратора был более развернутым.