# Многопоточность: Как организовать замкнутый цикл ожидания события?

Tags: java, многопоточность, gui

Как правильно организовать замкнутый цикл ожидания события не используя `Thread.sleep`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI start = new GUI();
    start.show();

    Thread generalThread = go();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(ObjRun) {
                while (true) {
                    if (ObjRun.getRUN()) {
                        generalThread.start();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: а зачем тогда нужен цикл, если не используется thread.sleep?

Comment: в смысле задача то какая? И чем не устраивает текущий подход?

Comment: Вам нужно в одном потоке подождать, когда второй поток дойдет до определенной точки?

Comment: Следует читать ответ на вопрос [Как организовать многопоточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871131/204920).

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Да, и этот поток должен быть всегда готов к очередному запуску другого потока, выполняющего поставленную задачу. По большому счёту я нашёл решение, но оно "экстраординарное" :)  Я его изобрёл пока вспоминал учебные материалы по multithreading и искал решения в интернете... Завтра выложу. Но, всё же хотелось бы увидеть профессиональные решения.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что значит " должен быть всегда готов к очередному запуску другого потока," Поток можно запустить только раз, "очередной запуск потока" - это оксюморон. Вероятно вы имеете ввиду, что-то другое.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA правильно, поток можно запустить только один раз. Но если вы используете GUI, то один поток работает до тех пор, пока программа не будет закрыта. Он отвечает за рабочее окно ("JFrame") и запускает процессы "по нажатию кнопки". Если интерфейс программы (методы  `JFrame` ) вынести в отдельный класс, то получится отдельный поток с которым нужно как-то взаимодействовать... Для этого я создаю ещё один поток "слушатель", который ждёт изменений состояния, и разделяю логику программы от графического интерфейса.

Comment: Можно конечно и микроскопом гвозди забивать, но молоток для этого и удобнее и дешевле... Нормальный GUI отдаёт события через колбеки и если в вашем случае есть возможность установить колбек на интересующее событие, то необходимость в изобретении велосипеда отпадает, просто пишете в колбеке код, который должен выполнить ваш "generalThread".